# Plesk SSH chown root:root admin by mistake

Tags: php, ssh, plesk

I have a Plesk server running the domain geekwiz.com. I was trying to run cronjobs using the scheduler on plesk however I was receiving emails of the cronjobs saying: `permission denied`.

I SSH into the server:

```
-bash-3.2$ ls -l var/www/vhosts/geekwiz.com/httpdocs/
ls: var/www/vhosts/geekwiz.com/httpdocs/: Permission denied
```

So I decided to try to make myself a root user like so

```
chown root:root /home/reopayadmin
```

Now my website isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this would break your site - what you did is change the owner of your home directly to root instead of giving yourself permission to see that directly.  You'll probably need root or sudo access to change it back.  Once you change it back, run:`sudo ls -l /your/site/directory` 
This will give you the permissions for the site.  Next, post what you're trying to do in cron so we can help ensure you set permissions in the right spot.

Comment: Well I don't know what to change it back to and yes weird that it broke my domain. and I know how to su - to run the cron manually but the idea was to give my user a superuser access permanently

Comment: That's generally not something that you'd like to do - it's dangerous to permanently give your user superuser privileges.  As for resetting the chown you did earlier, is your current user reopayadmin? If so, try chown reopayadmin:reopayadmin /home/reopayadmin